# VBA Excel 2016 - Import text file - Unhandleable error when filelen < 2

Tags: vba, excel, csv, import

I have a big problem that I need to solve!
I'm creating a workbook for people to open it on their machines so I must be sure that the code behaviors will be logical...

I'm stucked with a weird case!
I am trying to import a .csv file through a querytable. If that file contains less than 3 characters I get an "out of memory" (7) error that I can't handle with on error statement!!

Here I create the queryTable :

```
Private Function CreateProductsQueryTable(ByRef ws As Worksheet) As QueryTable

Set CreateProductsQueryTable = ws.QueryTables.Add("TEXT;" & GetPath(ws.Parent) & PRODUCTS_FILE_NAME, ws.range("A2"))

With CreateProductsQueryTable

    .name = CONNECTION_NAME
    .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
    .TextFilePlatform = 1252
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = False
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    .TextFileDecimalSeparator = ","
End With
End Function
```

No problems with that as you may check!

An here I try to refresh it :

```
Private Function Refresh(ByRef qt As QueryTable) As Boolean

With qt

        On Error GoTo emptyFile
        .Refresh True
        On Error GoTo 0

    If .ResultRange.Columns.count <> GetName(HEADERS_NAME, .Parent).RefersToRange.Columns.count Then

        .ResultRange = ""
        .Delete
    Else

        Refresh = True
    End If

    Exit Function

emptyFile:

        .ResultRange = ""
        .Delete
    End With
End Function
```

Despite the "on error goto emptyFile" statement I still get an "out of memory" error prompt highlighting the ".refresh" method, when my file contains 0, 1 or 2 characters..!! I just have to manually put a third character to get things work properly...
I really need to know if this behavior is intended and if it would be the same on any machine! If so I would just control the filelen! But what if this is a weird bug that happens for a random filesize like if a user get that unhandled error while trying to refresh with a 4 characters long file..?? That would be a mess ^^'

Comment: What is `BodyGrid`. Are you calling the `Refresh` function in a loop from another function? I would try getting rid of the `On Error` statements and stepping through the code. Rather than preventing problems, as you seem to think, they are probably masking problems. I always assume the bug is in my code, not in the program.

Comment: I see you didn't read what I wrote... My code works if the file contains 3 or more characters but doesn't otherwise ^^

The problem is not in my code... The problem is in the program! That's why I am asking here! I gave you the code to let you all build a similar workbook so you would let me know if you got the same bug...

As you may know "on error goto" is supposed to let the program continue in case of error but here, even with the statement, an error prompt is fired...

If I try to import through UI, when I select the file, nothing happens (bug) if the file is less long than 3 chars

Comment: yes, this is a flaw in Excel. Check filelen before updating.